# How can I update my droid x to the 2.2 operating system?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x

I'm trying to find a (hopefully official) place to update my droid x to 2.2 I'd appreciate any help/pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about phone -> system updates.

Answer (score 2):

OTA update went out already. You should have gotten it automatically.

What does `Settings |About phone | Version number` say? What about `Build number`?